# I am trying to use the read_html() i rvest to read a page, but the result is the Japanese version of the page and not the English

Tags: r, rvest

The website I am trying to read is https://www.pixiv.net/en/

When I try to read the page the html codes retrieved clearly indicate it's the Japanese version of the site:

```
> read_html("https://www.pixiv.net/en/")
{html_document}
<html lang="ja".........
```

I want the English version of the page (`<html lang="en"` when you open the page source on the site). Is there anything I can do to make that happen?

I have been using `read_html()` to read the page. I have tried setting up a user agent from https://xml2.r-lib.org/reference/read_xml.html but this is honestly a bit confusing to me. It doesn't seem apparent where I implement the user agent nor do I know if this is even the right solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link in your code instead:

```
https://www.pixiv.net/en/?lang=en&return_to=
```

It is from the bottom-left corner of the website:

[image]

Hope it's helpful.